# How can I convert Map to Set and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, foreach, set

`forEach()` method uses `value` variable twice. It's written that this is done in order to ensure the compatibility of Map and Set.

[Source](https://javascript.info/map-set#:%7E:text=That%E2%80%99s%20for%20compatibility%20with%20Map%20where%20the%20callback%20passed%20forEach%20has%20three%20arguments.%20Looks%20a%20bit%20strange%2C%20for%20sure.%20But%20may%20help%20to%20replace%20Map%20with%20Set%20in%20certain%20cases%20with%20ease%2C%20and%20vice%20versa.)

> That’s for compatibility with Map where the callback passed forEach has three arguments. Looks a bit strange, for sure. But may help to replace Map with Set in certain cases with ease, and vice versa.

```js
let set = new Set(["orange", "apple", "banana"]);

set.forEach((value, valueAgain, set) => {
  console.log(valueAgain); //"orange", "apple", "banana"
});
```

So, my question is how Set can convert into Set and vice versa? As I understand, there is no special method for this case.

Comment: What have you tried to attempt to convert it to a Map?

Comment: What do you mean by converting one to the other? A Map contains pairs of data (keys and values), a Set only contains single values. `forEach()` just treats a `Set` as if it's a `Map` where the keys and values are the same. But if you try to convert a `Map` to a `Set`, you'll lose the values.

Comment: @Barmar Don't know. I have this question after reading this tutorial. [Here](https://javascript.info/map-set#:~:text=That%E2%80%99s%20for%20compatibility)

Comment: You asked how to do it -- what result are expecting by doing it?

Comment: @Barmar Don't know. Just have question to this information. What was meant [here](https://javascript.info/map-set#:~:text=But%20may%20help%20to%20replace%20Map%20with%20Set%20in%20certain%20cases%20with%20ease%2C%20and%20vice%20versa.)? I'll leave this link in the question

Comment: That's not saying that you can convert a map to a set. It's saying that depending on what you're using it for, you might want to use the other instead. For instance, if you're using a `Map` but not using the values for anything, you could use a `Set` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is not that you can easily replace a set with a map in your code. If you do that, you touch the code anyway, and would have no trouble also rewriting the iteration.

The real benefit is that it allows writing code that can *handle both* at once. In your example:

```js
function print(collection) {
    collection.forEach((value, key) => {
        console.log(key, value);
    });
}

const set = new Set(["orange", "apple", "banana"]);
const map = new Map([[1, "peach"], [2, "pear"]]);

print(set); // works
print(map); // works the same
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not say anything about conversion.
It says that you can use the same function callback for the `Map` and the `Set`.

```
const set = new Set(["oranges", "apples", "bananas"]);
const map = new Map([
  ['cucumber', 500],
  ['tomatoes', 350],
  ['onion',    50]
]);
const print = (value, key) => console.log(value, key);
set.forEach(print)
// oranges oranges
// apples apples
// bananas bananas
map.forEach(print)
// 500 cucumber
// 350 tomatoes
// 50 onion
```